# Local or Server Based Crawler that Detects the PHP version of a script

Tags: php, version, detection

I have custom scripts that are were written near the change of php4 and php5 and I am looking to find all of the php4 versions easily so that I can rewrite them so that they work with php5.3. Is there a tool that can perform this on my local machine or the server?

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's almost impossible to detect clearly which script will throw errors in php5. Problem can by very small, and it can show up dynamically (like bad data type parsed as argument to function).

In your place, i would write simple directory tree "traveller" and scan .php files for deprecated function etc. (like is_a -> instanceOf change).

You can found some help here, to do some tool:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.incompatible.php

of course, also search for .php4 files and take a look for this ones.